# Getting error code -10670 when running a Mac Catalyst app in Xcode

Tags: swift, macos, xcode12, macos-big-sur, xcode12beta6

I am developing an app for iOS and also using Mac Catalyst to run on my Mac. The app runs fine on my iPhone but always shows an error on Catalyst. The code used to run fine before updating to Big Sur Beta 6 from Beta 5. Here's a screenshot of the error: [image: Here's a screenshot of the error]. Also the error in code blocks for anybody who wants to copy it.

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10670.)
Domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain
Code: -10670
User Info: {
    "_LSFunction" = "_LSOpenStuffCallLocal";
    "_LSLine" = 3664;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.0 (Build 20A5364e)
Xcode 12.0 (17210.1)
```

https://github.com/MysteryCoder456/VegieMato/tree/backend is the GitHub Repo if anybody wants to reproduce this (i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved with new Mac OS 11.0 Beta (20A5374g).

If your catalyst app has multi-window support, you may still need to kill your existing app before launching the new one.

Comment: It's back with the 10th Beta!

Answer (score 4):

Faced same issue after upgrading to macOS 11 Beta 6. Reported bug to Apple but meanwhile found workaround - Select Product in Xcode, select 'Show in Finder'. Launch it from Finder. Additional step, hopefully Apple will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. (I say had, I guess I still do, however I have a workaround) My App had been developed as iOS / iPadOS with Mac support. All has been working great throughout macOS 11 beta builds. Until today that is, when I, as you, updated to Beta 6. Upon attempting to run for macOS target I get the same error as you have posted.

After some googling I found https://www.virusbulletin.com/uploads/pdf/conference_slides/2015/Wardle-VB2015.pdf and had a go at simply opening the app directly from the build folder. Hey presto, it opened without any problems, I even cleaned out the build folder and built it again to make sure.

This would appear to be a problem that the next version of Xcode beta should fix. Until then, unless anybody can suggest a better fix, this will have to suffice for me at least :-(

Sam

Comment: Holy crap this actually worked. Thanks a lot I thought I would have to use Simulators for the rest of my life.

Comment: Beta 6 Unfortunately does not support running from Xcode currently. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659328).

Comment: It's 2023 and it still happens to me. Cost me many days to find this. I was adding `Entitlements.plist` as well and I thought it's because of that

Answer (score 0):

```
-10670
```

I was having this same error code upon installing a Developer ID Distributed, Auto Signed version of a catalyst app on a test machine, non M1 Chip, Mac Mini(Late 2014) with MacOS Version 12.0 Beta installed.

**The solution was to close the previously installed version of the app.** Before opening the new version that I Airdrop over to the test Mac machine.